# What does 'AlwaysResetOnEntry' do, and where would it be used?

Tags: 3d, animation, unreal-4, animation-states, animation-controller

---

In Unreal Animation Blueprints, each state has an option for `AlwaysResetOnEntry`.

[image]

The tooltip text for this is:

`Whether or not this state will ALWAYS reset its state on reentry, regardless of remaining weight`

---

**Question**

What does this do, exactly?

Additionally, what is a good example of where this would be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this reply from someone outside of Stack exchange, so I'll post it here to help others

---

Searched the code for bAlwaysResetOnEntry, looks like its used for animation state machines.

Implies its possible to re-enter a state while it is still the active state, and the reset flag would cause the state to re-trigger, possibly re-calling the OnStateEntered events.
Untitled

```c
if ((!bAlreadyActive || bForceReset) && !IsAConduitState(NewStateIndex))
        {
            // Initialize the new state since it's not part of an active transition (and thus not still initialized)
            FAnimationInitializeContext InitContext(Context.AnimInstanceProxy);
            StatePoseLinks[NewStateIndex].Initialize(InitContext);
            // Also call cache bones if needed
            // Note dont call CacheBones here if we are in the process of whole-graph initialization as a 'never updated' counter
            // will not perform its 'minimal update guard' duty and every call will end up getting though, performing duplicate work
            // over Save/UseCachedPose boundaries etc.
            // This is OK because CacheBones is actually called before updating the graph anyway after whole-graph initialization
            if(Context.AnimInstanceProxy->GetCachedBonesCounter().HasEverBeenUpdated())
            {
                ConditionallyCacheBonesForState(NewStateIndex, Context);
            }
        }
```

bForceReset is assigned bAlwaysResetOnEntry earlier.